# Why variable with __weak qualifier retains an object?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

Here is my code:

```
extern void _objc_autoreleasePoolPrint();

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSArray __weak *tmp = nil;

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSArray __strong *obj = [[NSArray alloc] init];

        NSLog(@"obj &: %p", obj);

        tmp = obj;

        NSLog(@"tmp &: %p", tmp);

        _objc_autoreleasePoolPrint();
    }

    NSLog(@"tmp: %@", tmp); // why not (null) ?


    return 0;
}
```

And console output:

```
    2013-05-01 22:14:32.966 SimpleConsoleObjectiveCApplicationWithARC[40660:f07] obj &: 0x7fedf9403110
2013-05-01 22:14:32.969 SimpleConsoleObjectiveCApplicationWithARC[40660:f07] tmp &: 0x7fedf9403110
objc[40660]: ##############
objc[40660]: AUTORELEASE POOLS for thread 0x7fff751af180
objc[40660]: 2 releases pending.
objc[40660]: [0x7fedf9805000]  ................  PAGE  (hot) (cold)
objc[40660]: [0x7fedf9805038]  ################  POOL 0x7fedf9805038
objc[40660]: [0x7fedf9805040]    0x7fedf9403110  __NSArrayI
objc[40660]: ##############
2013-05-01 22:14:32.971 SimpleConsoleObjectiveCApplicationWithARC[40660:f07] tmp: (
)
```

**PS #1**

Changed NSArray to NSMutableArray and tmp variable became nil.

```
extern void _objc_autoreleasePoolPrint();

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSMutableArray __weak *tmp = nil;

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSMutableArray __strong *obj = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        NSLog(@"obj &: %p", obj);

        tmp = obj;

        NSLog(@"tmp &: %p", tmp);

        _objc_autoreleasePoolPrint();
    }

    NSLog(@"tmp: %@", tmp);


    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody explain me why it works this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `[[NSArray alloc] init]` returns a "shared instance" of an empty `NSArray`:

```
NSArray *a = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSArray *b = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSLog(@"a &: %p", a);
NSLog(@"b &: %p", b);
```

Output:

```
    a &: 0x100103110
    b &: 0x100103110
```

This "shared instance" continues to exist even if your strong reference `obj` is gone,
therefore the weak pointer is not set to `nil`.

Obviously, `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` cannot return a shared instance.

Comment: Martin R, yes, all immutable classes are returning "shared instance" (have checked NSString, NSDictionary etc), but is there any way to pass this "feature"?

Comment: @AndrewShmig: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need the weak reference to become nil?

Comment: Martin R, I am trying to understand WHY __weak is not working as it is expected to work after variable obj leaves its scope.

Comment: @AndrewShmig: A weak pointer is set to nil if the object it points to is *destroyed*, not if *your* pointer to the object leaves the scope. The NSArray class keeps its own strong pointer to the shared instance, therefore the object is not destroyed even if your pointer obj leaves the scope.