# NSObject released, NSString, NSArray not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

If I write -

```
NSObject *a = [[NSObject alloc] init]; // or UIView or something
[a release];
NSLog(@"a = %@", a); // causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS, fine
```

But, if I write -

```
NSArray *a = [[NSArray alloc] init]; // or NSString or NSDictionary
[a release];
NSLog(@"a = %@", a); // no crash, prints empty array or string
```

Why second case doesn't cause bad access, since it's released?

Answer (score 8):

Accessing a released object doesn't have to make the application crash immediately.

Note than even if you release the object, the memory stays there for some time, with the same contents. You will get a crash only if the object memory has already been overwritten by some other object. And note that even with overwritten memory you don't have to get a crash. You can get only some very strange behavior (e.g. when the object is a `NSString`, it can get different contents).

Basically, this behavior is totally random. Using a released object can make your application crash immediately or in 5 minutes or in 2 hours.

**Edit:**
Thanks to *Martin R* for an interesting comment. It seems that an array created by `[[NSArray alloc] init]`, that is, empty immutable array, returns always the same instance. That means your `release` won't make it to be deallocated. However, this behavior can easily change, can differ between compilers or OS versions.

Comment: You are faster than me, I was going to answer the exact same way, but I didn't even get one word typed.  +1

Comment: But releasing NSObject or UIView etc are definitely crashing immediately, while NSArray or NSString etc are definitely not crashing immediately. So some difference must be there in memory use, release case of array or string. What is that?

Comment: See **random**.  In this case it will crash for NSObject, but not for NSArray.  If you compile with different options it might not behave that way.  How memory is used by the OS differs depending on many factors.  That is the difference between *released* and *deallocated*

Comment: The difference is that in the second case you get a shared instance that is not deallocated at all, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323908/why-variable-with-weak-qualifier-retains-an-object/16324350#16324350.

Comment: @MartinR Knows better haha.  I thought this method (flywheeling it is called) only applied to NSString, NSNumber, etc

Comment: @borrrden, I think you talking about flyweight?

Comment: !!!  Yes, that's it.  Hmm I wonder why I remembered it wrong (too much thinking about car engines? o,0)