# Why NSString and NSNumber are not released after inserting it into [NSHashTable weakObjectsHashTable]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, hashtable

I was trying to use NSHashTable to store some object pointers with weak references. During learning, I found that NSString(NSNumber) objects are not released after inserting it into [NSHashTable weakObjectsHashTable]. Any self defined class will work otherwise.

Any idea about why NSString(NSNumber) objects are not released?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface C : NSObject

@property(nonatomic) NSHashTable *hashTable;

@end

@implementation C

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _hashTable = [NSHashTable weakObjectsHashTable];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addObject:(NSObject *)obj {
    [self.hashTable addObject:obj];
}

- (void)printAllObjects {
    NSLog(@"Members: %@", [self.hashTable allObjects]);
    [[self.hashTable allObjects] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        NSLog(@"%p\n", obj);
    }];
}

+ (void)hi:(C *)c {
    @autoreleasepool {
      NSString *s;
      for(int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
        s = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", i];
        [c addObject:s];
      } 
    }
}

@end

void hi(C *c) {
    NSString *i = @"hi";
    NSLog(@"%p", i);
    [c addObject:i];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    C *c = [[C alloc] init];

    @autoreleasepool {
        [C hi:c];
    }
    [c printAllObjects];
}
```

Xcode Version is 8.1 (8B62) and output is:

```
2016-12-12 11:16:30.361 0x7fff9106c920
2016-12-12 11:16:30.362 Members: (
    ""
)
2016-12-12 11:16:30.362 0x7fff9106c920
```

Comment: Probably `[[NSString alloc] init]` returns a "shared instance" which is never released. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323908/why-variable-with-weak-qualifier-retains-an-object for a similar question.

Comment: `NSString` and `NSNumber` have lots of optimizations that affect the way they are memory-managed.  If you try it with a long string of random characters you should see it behave the same way it does with other objects.

Comment: @dan So NSStrings will be released in some unknown condition?

Comment: +1 to dan's comment. For example, if you poke around in the debugger you might find that some of your strings are instances of `NSTaggedPointerString`, where memory management really gets interesting.

Comment: @dan Thank you. I think you solved my question. Closing this question.